# Testing a Java program on a virtual 1024 core machine

Tags: java, parallel-processing, simulation

I have written a Java application (parallel), and have tested it on a 16 core machine, but I need to test it on an up to 1024 core machine. Though it's not feasible for me to get access to any such physical machine.

Are there ways of running a Java program on a simulated 1024 core machine?

EDIT: Purpose of this testing
I am trying to replace locks using lock-free protocol in my application , and running it on 16 cores is giving me a good performance, but i want to test it on larger core system also, to find out bottle-neck. Any idea whether we can do so using virtualmachines ?

Comment: at least comment, what went wrong ?

Comment: I didn't -1 you, but you haven't actually asked a question here. Also, to simulate a more powerful machine on a less powerful machine isn't going to work too well - look at the specs needed to run an emulator for an old console, you need 5-10 times the processing power the original console had.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but isn't using 1024 threads on a 16 core machine simulating a 1024 core machine.  I don't believe there are any machines which allow a single Java process across so many cores. Azul sell servers with hundreds of cores but even they suggest "tens of cores" is a more practical size. http://www.azulsystems.com/solutions/java-scalability-overview

Comment: @peter thanks for suggestion, but making m threads on n core machine where m>n, will not be giving advantage of parallelism. So i was thinking some way like SESC simulator provides or virtual machines that can emulate as much cores as you need.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by testing it on 1024 cores? If it's performance bottlenecks you are trying to find, testing it on the target hardware is the only reliable way.

Comment: but simulations also provides us nearly expected performance so if we don't have target hardware then what are the other options ?

Comment: Simulations give you an indication of expected performance, but don't actually give you that performance. e.g. if a test takes 30 minutes on 16 cores, the simulation might tell you it would take 1 minute on 1024 core, but will actually take 300 minutes to determine that. It will only be faster in simulated time, but in reality be slower.  Simulating how a real multi-threaded application will behave is very hard to be accurate, so you are likely to have a large margin of error compared to how it would be behave on a real machine.

Comment: Also things such as CPU caches, memory bandwidth etc. will affect performance on real hardware and it will be nearly impossible for a simulation to emulate them accurately. IIRC in some interview the Azul folk said that a typical bottleneck, when moving applications to their many-hundred-core Vega hardware, is using a volatile field or counter from all threads - there maintaining cache coherence kills performance.

Comment: but whenever we simulate things we do not care about how long it will take to simulate, only the simulation output matters to us. And usually while simulation we compare things ( like one program against better one ), so things are going to be remain same for both, so simulation can give nearly correct performance gain... Though it won't be giving same as real hardware i agree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are asking how to run a java app on a simulator that can simulate more than one core.

I don't know how effective it would be because at the metal level you would still only have 16 cores so my understanding would be that only 16 things can happen at the same time. Due to the speed of the machinery it might appear that more is going on, but it's not.

So I'm thinking you need to outline what sort of test you are thinking of because some tests might be ok on a simulator (probably running multiple threads to simulate the extra cores), but other tests would probably not.

I don't know what type of app you are writing that would need to run on such machinery (code breaking? massive simulations ?) but I'd expect what you would be looking for was to establish the overhead of adding more cores. You could probably do this by measuring with the code on one core, 2 cores, 4 cores, 6 cores, etc and extrapolating up. But it would still be a guess because there may be other hardware/software factors that only kick in after a certain number of cores are running. I/O for example.

Comment: it would be effective , it's like superscalar simulator that exploits parallelism at ilp level ( though native metal doesn't provides that...). that's the purpose of simulation : you don't have hardware but you can achieve speedup (simulated speedup .)..